# Angular FromControl disable/enable base on condition and Validators

Tags: angular, forms

i'm coding a simple login for now. you can find some of the code here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qf7pju 
now i have few problems: 
1. when i press login right away to submit i get a success even when the required fields are empty. 
2. i want that Field B select input will be disabled until Field A isn't empty but i cant manage to that. 
3. i use `(keyup)` event in the 'code' text input to manipulate the input by the user but the validation probably try to validate the input by my pattern before i finish manipulating the text.

eventually these are a lot of small things that cause me a lot of trouble and i can use some help.
 **thx**

Comment: Please see the updated answer.

Comment: Please include the relevant code in the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Login Right away on Submit?  <strike>Why don't you something like:</strike>

   `<button type="submit" [disabled]="!(loginForm?.valid)"
   mat-button>Login</button>`

   That is because you have assigned default values to the form
   controls you defined: For example when you have something like:

   ```
   this.loginForm.addControl('fcs', new FormControl(this.fcs, Validators.required));
   ```

   Here 'this.fcs' is the default value, which
   makes the control valid, you would rather want something like:

   ```
    this.loginForm.addControl('fcs', new FormControl('', Validators.required));
   ```

   I was having some problem in editing in stackblitz, here are the
   changes you can try:

   I have used: FormBuilder(this is optional, you can create the form
   model as are already creating, just don't give default valid values)

   ```
   fieldBDisabled:boolean = true;
    ...
   constructor(private _fb: FormBuilder) { } 
   ... 


   createForm() {
   this.loginForm = this._fb.group({
     'fas': ['', Validators.required],
     'fbs': [{value: '', disabled: this.fieldBDisabled}, Validators.required],
     'fcs': ['', Validators.required],
     'code': ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.pattern('[0-9]{5}')])],
   });
   ```

   }

   Now on click of Login it should print `Failed`
2. I guess you wanted to say, Field B disabled (please correct me if
   that's not what you desire) until we fill Field A, in that case:

   ```
   <mat-select [disabled]=!"(loginForm?.controls['fbs']?.value)" placeholder="FieldB" formControlName="fbs" []>
   </mat-select>
   ```

   We don't use angular's `[disabled]`, this will mix `template driven
   forms with reactive forms`. Rather we initialize FieldB as disabled
   and enable it when we see a change in the value of the fieldA, (see the onblur event)

   ```
   <mat-select placeholder="Field A" name="one" (blur)="isFieldAValid()" formControlName="fas">
       <mat-option *ngFor="let fa of fas" value="{{fa}}">{{fa}}</mat-option>
   </mat-select>


   isFieldAValid() {
       if (this.loginForm.get('fas').valid) {
         this.loginForm.get('fbs').enable();
       }
   }
   ```
3. If you want to validate your third field, then why don't add the
   validator in the form control itself instead of using the `(keyup)`
   event?

   ```
   this.loginForm.addControl('code', new FormControl(this.code, Validators.compose([
     Validators.pattern('[0-9]{5}'), this.codeInput.bind(this)]))) </strike>
   ```

   If you are validating, then this should still work, just don't give the initial default value if the field is required,

   ```
   'code': ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.pattern('[0-9]{5}'), this.codeInput.bind(this)]])],
   ```

   and then make your function `codeInput()` something like:

   `codeInput(control: FormControl) {...}`

Comment: nope ;-( 
 1. i can press login at start because the form is apparently valid at start (the same reason it gave me success)
2. just didn't work. 
3. made an compilation error  cause it is trying to get a value of an object that wasn't created yet.

u can try it on the stackbliz editor to check it. Still thank u very much